# Android 7.0 ble scan no result

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-7.0-nougat

When I start ble(Bluetooth Le) scan for seconds, then stop scan. Then start, then stop...
after about 5-8 Loops, the start action will be *No effect* ,this means no scan record can be received.
1.This condition only appears on Android 7.0 or above(7.1.1);
2.I have tried two scan method: BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() and Scanner.startScan(), no difference .

```
private void scanToggle(final boolean enable) {
    mScanHandler.removeCallbacks(scanTask);
    if (enable) {
        TelinkLog.i("ADV#scanner#startScan");
        scanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        scanner.startScan(null, settings, scanCallback);
        mScanning = true;
        mDeviceList.clear();
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       //mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
        mScanHandler.postDelayed(scanTask, SCAN_PERIOD);
    } else {
        TelinkLog.i("ADV#scanToggle#stopScan");
        mScanning = false;
        //mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
        scanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}


private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        TelinkLog.d("scan:" + device.getName());
        for (AdvDevice advDevice : mDeviceList) {
            if (device.getAddress().equals(advDevice.device.getAddress())) return;
        }
        mDeviceList.add(new AdvDevice(device, rssi, scanRecord));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};

private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        for (AdvDevice advDevice : mDeviceList) {
            if (result.getDevice().getAddress().equals(advDevice.device.getAddress())) return;
        }
        mDeviceList.add(new AdvDevice(result.getDevice(), result.getRssi(), result.getScanRecord().getBytes()));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    }
};
```

Comment: Shoud I do something when stop scan?

Comment: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/418 . The same problem

Comment: How many seconds do you scan each time and how long time do you wait until you start again?

Comment: Did you get it to work? You then need to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably running into the new and undocumented behavior changes in Android 7 that prevent apps from scanning too often.

I wrote a blog post about it:
https://blog.classycode.com/undocumented-android-7-ble-behavior-changes-d1a9bd87d983

Answer (score 4):

I had also this kind of problem. It is solved by enabling Location. In android, we need to enable Location for scan near by devices. So please check location is enable or not. Below code is useful. I hope it works, in my case it works good.

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    buildAlertMessageNoGps(mainActivity);
}else{ //scanning part}


public void  buildAlertMessageNoGps(MainActivity mainActivity){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it? It is required for this application.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    mainActivity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), MainActivity.LOCATION_ENABLE);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    mainActivity.finishAffinity();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

After on location start scanning and get scanning result.

Comment: Tks for reply. However I test this on location opened.

Comment: This is one possible cause, but on Android 7 other factors can come into play. Check my answer below, maybe it's the case for you.

Comment: You will see this in Logcat : `java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results`. I don't know if `GPS_PROVIDER ` is the right permission here ... it seens a bit overkill to start a bt scan ? And undocumented...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you stop and re-start your scan only after **6 seconds** for all devices with Android N and above.

This is as per the introduced restriction where apps are allowed to scan a maximum of 5 times in 30 seconds.

> We’ve changed the BLE Scanning behavior starting in DP4. We’ll prevent
>   applications from starting and stopping scans more than 5 times in 30
>   seconds. For long running scans, we’ll convert them into opportunistic
>   scans.

Refer to this discussion [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/418)

Answer (score 1):

You will also have to include `location permissions` in your ***Manifest*** or else your search will not return anything. This is mandatory I would say for `Bluetooth` and `Wifi` searches.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

As the in the developer section for BLE in Android.

[image]