# Android BLE SCAN getting stopped in 30 secs in Foreground Service after sending the app to background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

We have BLE scan implemented in a **ForegroundService** our app, when we target the app from **targetSDKVersion 31 (Android 12)** and try to scan when app is in background,  the scan is getting stopped exactly after 30 secs ..

Note:- We have used the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICES_FROM_BACKGROUND"/>

<permission android:name="android.permission.START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged|vendorPrivileged|oem|verifier" />
```

Do we need to change the way we are scanning or do we add any permissions or settings ???

Please help

Comment: *Do we need to change the way we are scanning* - How we can know that without seeing the relevant scanning code logic? What about the runtime permissions? Do you handle them properly? Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842249/12749998) to check whether you handle runtime permissions correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to scan in the background, you need to add the **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** to your permissions (both in the manifest file and at runtime). There are a few other restrictions when it comes to scanning in the background; the articles below do a good job covering them and how to temporarily overcome them:-

- [Restrictions when scanning background in Android 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180364/restrictions-when-scanning-in-background-on-android-10)
- [ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
- [Beacond detection with Android 8](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8)
- [Background BLE scan in DOZE mode](https://proandroiddev.com/background-ble-scan-in-doze-mode-on-android-devices-3c2ce1764570)
- [Android BLE scan stops after a couple of minutes in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228337/android-ble-scan-stops-after-a-couple-of-minutes-in-background)

Comment: Haven't all these permission settings changed for Bluetooth in Android 12?

Comment: I'm not sure, I believe they are still required (especially the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) but perhaps there were other changes that I am not aware of. This is a comprehensive link from the Android Developer website that includes the permissions needed for Android 12 and higher: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions